# How can I "delete" the last word, using iOS dictation feature?

Tags: ios, siri, voice-dictation, undo-redo

iOS dictation is a great feature, which mostly works both for Siri and for apps supporting an onscreen keyboard.

However: is there a voice command I can use to backspace or delete the last word?  I found a good guide here, but there is no delete command: http://www.siriuserguide.com/siri-dictation-guide/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't seem like it is possible.

The closest I have seen is to use 'shake to undo' which will then select your entire last phrase/sentence. It's then possible to adjust that selection & delete as required.

Not what you wanted, I'm aware.

Comment: There are some "editing" commands you can tell Siri, e.g., saying "new line" will cause Siri to move to the next line -- but I haven't found anything for deleting the last word either.

Answer (score 1):

just figured it out, you have to say "select word" and then say "delete that".. its working for me !

Comment: It doesn't work for me (iOS 10). It just writes the words literally

Comment: Still does not work, just tried it in iOS 14.3.

Comment: I think you have to enable voice control for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this for a while, until I finally figured out the way, in which Apple UX designer intended for us to use this feature: "If dictation isn’t sure what word it heard, you'll see a blue line under the transcribed word so you can check it for accuracy. To make corrections, tap the underlined word, then select the correct spelling. To replace a word, double-tap it, tap the microphone button , then say it again, and tap the keyboard button iPhone keyboard."

here is the list of all supported commands, and delete isn't one of them: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208343

The good news is, if dictation made a mistake, you can just tap the keyboard button, then tap on the underlined word, and it will show you the alternatives.  This works pretty well for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

"delete this" works for me using mac dictation

Comment: The question is about iOS dictation.